# how can I write function with optional output parameters in python

Tags: python

how can I write function with optional output parameters.
In example

1) `mat = ReadBinFile(filename)`
or
2) `[mat,titles] = ReadBinFile(filename)`

if i finished the "ReadBinFile" function with

```
return mat,titles
```

i have a tuple in "mat" in the first example

Thank You for the Help

Comment: What is your use case for this? If you don't want the second tuple element, just ignore it.

Comment: You can't do this.  It's not really a great idea anyway.  Just unpack the result and discard any elements you don't want.

Comment: Using a generator over a tuple does have the advantage of potentially lowering the time (if each element takes a while to get)

Comment: @mhawke, I need to provide two types of use

Comment: So sometimes you want to return a single object, and sometimes a list.  What determines which is which?  Remember that Python only has untyped names on the LHS, so you can't even use the syntax that you show in the second example.  Are the two types of use within the same code unit?  I'm thinking that you could have two functions, then just assign `ReadBinFile` to the correct one for the relevant code unit.  But it would be horrible to support, I suggest you really need to look at your design again.

Comment: Return a dictionary of outputs and access them by key

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this without indicating to the function which return type is required, or masking the function name (see my comment).

Let me demonstrate why.

In Perl we can do this, by testing the *context* of the call.  The first (single return value) would be scalar context, and the second in list context.  We could test using a function called `wantarray` (Google "python wantarray" - other search engines are available).  Perl, for this reason and many others, is unusual if not unique.

Python doesn't work like that, even though introspection can be taken to extremes compared to other languages.  The form of an assignment is:

```
 name = object
```

where `name` is a typeless reference.  So:

```
 mat = ReadBinFile(filename)
```

Even if, by some sneaky means, we inspected the byte-code, we would have no way of knowing what class of object `mat` is supposed to reference.  A `list`, a `tuple`, an `int`, a `bird`, a `plane`?

The syntax you show:

```
[mat,titles] = ReadBinFile(filename)
```

is a puzzle.  Although valid, it has no practical difference to:

```
mat,titles = ReadBinFile(filename)
```

which of course is a tuple.  So, how can we tell if:

```
mat = ReadBinFile(filename)
```

should be a `tuple`, a `list`, or whatever class of object `mat` is supposed to reference.

After all that, in my opinion returning objects of different classes is a dubious practice, even in Perl.  There are a few exceptions, returning `None` under some circumstances for example.  Why dubious?  Because the code becomes difficult to read, modify, and support.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have researched, the only convincing way I found by using "_" but this when you call the function, not inside it. As an example:

`mat, _= ReadBinFile(filename)` if you want the "mat"

`_, title= ReadBinFile(filename)` if you want the "title"

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways to do this. One is to accept an argument that determines the return value. The second, (and more interesting) is to return a generator.

```
def ReadBinFile(filename):
   yield mat
   yield titles

mat,titles = ReadBinFile(filename)
```

This will let you get only the first or get the first n return values.

Comment: This doesn't really work.  If you do `mat = ReadBinFile(filename)`, `mat` will get the generator itself, not the first yielded value.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do exactly what you want to do. In Python, you can't change the syntax, but you can get functional results. I'm pretty sure that this provides all the functionality you are looking for.